# Display Photo from URL in iOS 8 Today View Widget

Tags: photos, ios, url, widgets

I've got a old web cam that takes an image every 5 minutes and uploads it to an FTP site (which I can access from an http url).  I'm looking for a simple iOS 8 today view widget that I can point to this URL so that I always have the most recent web cam photo in the notifications panel. For the life of me, I can't find a widget that offers this simple functionality.

Does anyone know of an app I can use to achieve this goal? At this point, I don't even mind writing a script to produce and RSS feed, etc. to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for such a webcam widget and also couldn't find one to suit my needs.
But as you mentioned RSS there is one that can do that ([Photo of the Day Widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-of-the-day-widget/id885247173?mt=8) by Francis Bonnin) however you can't set a refresh rate for it in the app/widget settings. I also couldn't get it to work with a webcam url (JPG url or page where the webcam e.g. JPG is shown) or create an RSS feed via existing online tools for the image link or webcam page. If you know how it can be done for webcams at other websites let me know. I'm trying to run a script on my own webcam with one or more webcams from other website by looking into [this W3School RSS image element code](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp).

I did receive a good response from the developers Lennart Reiher (PhotoBar widget) and Francis Bonnin (which created e.g. Photo of the Day widget) which were thinking about creating a new app/widget after my e-mail to them. They said that the new widget could have one or multiple webcam URLs (e.g. to a JPG) and hopefully also have a refresh rate option in it.

Also take a look at the huge iOS8 widget list (i'm also updating in the start topic almost daily at MacRumors forum at iOS8 sub category in the sticky widget megathread topic). I also created a Photo category there. 
If you found a widget or build one yourself let me know here and maybe also there.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to use the [Photo of the Day widget](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-of-the-day-widget/id885247173?mt=8) to show webcam images in the notification center but but you need to manually add your favorite webcam link (to a JPG image) to [this URL](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=47f1c995595b78470bd1012706e16a84) and choose a name of your choice. Then press 'Run Pipe' > Then press 'Get RSS' and copy the link to the widget and select custom RSS feed.

Please keep in mind that Yahoo Pipes could have a delay of approx 5 minutes. Also some webcams only refresh every 5/10 minutes or even once an hour. Also some webcams stop refreshing around 16.00CET (European Alps) and then are refreshing again the next morning.

Please keep in mind that the webcam you have found needs to have a permanent URL so e.g.:

> http://cms.zugspitze.de/static/webcams/k03.jpg

So should not include a date/time within the JPG file name otherwise you will keep seeing the same old webcam image from that timestamp.

I already contacted the developer of this widget and also the developer of another widget Photo Bar and both responded to my e-mail and said they would probably try to build another widget with the webcam option without RSS feed so a direct link to a JPG for example and an auto refresh option.

Example result:
[image: Photo of the Day Widget with Webcam images]

I already contacted the developer of this widget and also the developer of another widget Photo Bar and both responded to my e-mail and said they would probably try to build another widget with the webcam option without RSS feed so a direct link to a JPG for example and an auto refresh option.

Answer (score 0):

There is already one being made by the maker of LiveImageView. It has been around for quite sometime. http://modmyi.com/info/liveimageview.d.php
This is being made to run on iOS 8 without jailbreak and will be on the AppStore very soon. Testing out next week for dev. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 5th of December there are a few webcam widgets available:

-**[AlpenCams](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alpencams/id556445432?l=en&mt=8)**

-**[Winterberg Webcams](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/winterberg-webcams/id587023116?l=en&mt=8)**

-**[Feldberg Webcams](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feldberg-webcams/id604701810?l=en&mt=8)**

I'm using AlpenCams. It still needs some tweaking (search improvement or add your own webcam URL for example but it is a start) see also my remarks in Dutch forum topic [here](http://www.wintersporters.nl/forum/topic/166148?page=3) where also the developer 'EricH' is active.

[image]

I expect that we are also seeing another widget soon in the App Store (the one that was previously also mentioned by Nokto.